# Glitches - Spline edit mode - Blender 3.6.1

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, vertices, transforms

[image]See the video that shows the problem.
https://youtu.be/GJ8Ctx0GOQY

Has anyone experienced glitches when orbiting around a spline while in edit mode?
Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: That looks like a graphics driver problem. Have you checked that you have the latest drivers installed for your graphics card?

Comment: I'm using macOS and everything seems up to date

Comment: Perhaps someone here who uses macOS can comment, but that still looks like a graphics problem to me whatever machine you're using.

Comment: I have the same glitches. MacOS on M1 Max here.

Comment: This is almost 100% a hardware problem. Make sure your material is at least up to par with the minimal requirements. https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix!

I got the same glitching problem when trying to edit bezier curve points. I'm on a 2023 Mac Mini M2 Pro, so couldn't have been outdated hardware.

Turning off "Show Overlays" Shift,Command,Z turns off the glitching. Just can't see the points.